# DHCP on main interface (eth1) and static on eth1:0

Tags: dhcp, static-ip, centos6.5

So the configuration is a bit weird, from our internet provider we get an IP via DHCP, there's also a whole subnet that's routed to this IP.

I solved it by adding a second interface with the static IPs (normally you would put a router in between and lose 1 IP), so now to the problem:

Every time the DHCP lease expires and IP is renewed, the interface `eth1:0` state is changed to down.

Configuration for `eth1`:

```
DEVICE=eth1
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
PEERDNS=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DHCP_HOSTNAME=router.xxx.xxx
```

Configuration for `eth1:0`:

```
DEVICE=eth1:0
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
```

I hope the solution is a simple option I forgot, thanks for any help!

dhclient version:

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.1.1-P1
Copyright 2004-2010 Internet Systems Consortium.
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved via a dhclient hook script under /etc/dhcp/ in my case I named the file  **dhclient-eth1-up-hooks** which is executed when eth1 is switched up.

Inside the script I have a simple

```
ifconfig eth1:0 inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx netmask 255.255.255.248
```